# Fundamental theorem of Algebra using ideas of complex singularities

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Below is an excerpt from Arnold's Theory of Catastrophes (I haven't got an American edition, so translating from Russian).

Where I can read about it in more detail? Not only regarding polynomials. As for the excerpt, can someone please clarify what equation is he talking about? And a bit more details on how it devides the space. So I'm a bit confused by the first part.

So:

Consider the space of polynomials of fixed degree with complex coefficients. "Singular" objects - polynomials with multiple roots - are defined by a single complex equations (= two real equations) on the coefficients.

Therefore, the set of singular objects has codimension two and does not divide the space of all objects.

Therefore, any two of non-special complex object - polynomials without multiple roots - are connected by continuous path, consisting of non-singular objects only (in our case, polynomials without multiple roots).

But small deformation of non-singular object does not change its topology (in our case the number of roots of a polynomial without multiple roots does not change when we change coefficients a little).

Therefore, we can study only a single non-singular object to find out such an invariant. In our case it will be $(x - x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$